# Integral over compact boundary is finite in the context of potential function

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Consider some bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is a smooth submanifold of dimension $(n-1)$ and fix some point $x_0\in \partial\Omega$. Now I want to prove, that

$$\int\limits_{\partial\Omega}\frac{1}{\Vert x-x_0 \Vert^{n-\frac{3}{2}}}d\sigma(x)<\infty,$$ whereas $d\sigma(x)$ denotes the standard induced measure on $\partial\Omega$.

I'm wondering if one can rewrite this integral as a volume integral over some bounded domain. Because the function under the integral sign is locally integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure. But I'm worried about the singularity at the boundary point $x_0$...

Would you be so kind and help me?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a surface integral?

Comment: I know the definition, but I have not much experience in calculation of integrals over surfaces. Suppose we want to calculate the integral over some domain $\partial\Omega\cap B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ for some small $\epsilon >0$. Then one would take some coordinate chart $\varphi: U\rightarrow \partial \Omega\cap B_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ and the integral one has to solve should be: $\int_{U}\Vert\varphi(x)-x_0 \Vert^{-n+\frac{3}{2}}dx$. Unfortunately I don't see how this integral is finite....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a translation and a rotation, we can assume without lost of generality that $x_0=0$ and there is a function $g:(-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial\Omega \cap B(0,r)$ is the graph of $g$ for some $r>0$ and $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)=0$.

Let $x'=(x_1,x_2,...,x_{N-1})$, $x=(x',x_N)$ and $Q(x)=(x',g(x')+x_n)$ for $x'\in (-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}$ and $x_n\in (-\beta,\beta)$. We have that $$\int_{\partial\Omega \cap B(0,r)}\frac{1}{|y|^{N-3/2}}d\sigma=\int_{(-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}}\frac{1}{|Q(x',0)|^{N-3/2}}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{\partial g(x')}{\partial x'_i}\right)^2\right)^{1/2}dx'\tag{1}$$

By one hand, there is a constanct $C>0$ such that $$\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{\partial g(x')}{\partial x'_i}\right)^2\right)^{1/2}\le C,\ \forall\ x'\in (-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}.\tag{2}$$

On the other hand $$|(x',0)|\le |Q(x',0)|,\  x'\in (-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}.\tag{3}$$

Therefore, combining $(1)$-$(3)$, we conlcude that $$\int_{\partial\Omega \cap B(0,r)}\frac{1}{|y|^{N-3/2}}d\sigma \le C\int_{(-\alpha,\alpha)^{N-1}}\frac{1}{|x'|^{N-3/2}}dx'.$$

From here, as you have said in you post, the conclusion is straigthforward.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was a nice idea, which I have to keep in mind. Best Regards.:-)